# Conditional Flow Issue depending on Object Properties using Auth0 and GraphQL Authentication

Tags: graphql, auth0, apollo-server

I am trying to construct a graphql context secured with Auth0 using Typescript which can support both authenticated and public routes.

I have an authValidate function which returns an object with 3 different possibilities: 1. No token provided 2. Token is Invalid 3. Token is valid therefore can proceed to get User info

The shape of the object thus will be one of the following...

```
      { error: 'No token provided' }

      { error:
        { JsonWebTokenError: invalid token

      { decoded:
        { email: 'John',
```

```
 context: async ({ req }) => {
      const { authorization: token } = req.headers;      

      const res: any = await isTokenValid(token);
```

I need advise on how I should code the flow. If I call res.error or res.decoded, res.error or res.decoded could be invalid either way depending on the result of the isTokenValid call

Appreciate if someone can guide me on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the issue on the conditional flow. Below is my solution if it helps someone

**index.ts**

```
import * as express from "express";
import { ApolloServer, AuthenticationError } from "apollo-server-express";
import * as depthLimit from "graphql-depth-limit";
import { createServer } from "http";
import * as compression from "compression";
import * as cors from "cors";

import typeDefs from "./typeDefs";
import resolvers from "./resolvers";
// import { typeDefs, resolvers } from "./utils/temp_graph";
import { isTokenValid } from "./utils/authValidate";
import User from "./models/User";
import Task from "./models/Task";
import { findOrMakeUser } from "./utils/findOrMakeUser";
import "./config/db";

(async () => {
  const app = express();

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    validationRules: [depthLimit(7)],
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: async ({ req }) => {
      const token = req.headers.authorization || "";

      let currentUser = null;

      if (token) {
        const { error, decoded }: any = await isTokenValid(token);

        if (error) {
          throw new AuthenticationError("Invalid Token. Access Denied!");
        }

        currentUser = await findOrMakeUser(decoded.email);
      }

      return {
        req,
        currentUser,
        User,
        Task,
      };
    },
  });

  app.use(cors());
  app.use(compression());

  server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: "/graphql" });

  const httpServer = createServer(app);

  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  httpServer.listen({ port: PORT }, (): void =>
    console.log(
      `\n      GraphQL is now running on http://localhost:${PORT}/graphql`
    )
  );
})();
```

**utils/authValidate.ts**

```
require("dotenv").config();
import * as jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import * as jwksClient from "jwks-rsa";

const client = jwksClient({
  jwksUri: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/.well-known/jwks.json`,
});

const options = {
  audience: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENTID,
  issuer: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/`,
  algorithms: ["RS256"],
};

function getKey(header: any, callback: any) {
  client.getSigningKey(header.kid, function (_: any, key: any) {
    const signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey;
    callback(null, signingKey);
  });
}

async function isTokenValid(token: any) {
  if (token) {
    const result = new Promise((resolve, __) => {
      jwt.verify(token, getKey, options as any, (error, decoded) => {
        if (error) {
          resolve({ error });
        }
        if (decoded) {
          resolve({ decoded });
        }
      });
    });

    return result;
  }

  return { error: "No token provided" };
}

export { isTokenValid };
```

**resolvers/middlewares.ts**

```
const { skip } = require("graphql-resolvers");

export const isAuthenticated = async (
  _: any,
  __: any,
  { currentUser }: any
) => {
  if (!currentUser) {
    throw new Error("Access Denied! Please authenticate to proceed");
  }

  return skip;
};
```

**utils/findOrMakeUser.ts**

```
import User from "../models/User";

const findOrMakeUser = async (email: any) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (!user) {
    const newUser = new User({ email });
    const result = await newUser.save();
    console.log("findOrMakeUser result", result);
    return result;
  }

  return user;
};

export { findOrMakeUser };
```